# How to restore docker images which are removed by `docker rmi` command?

Tags: docker

I issued command `docker rmi 0d20855ef162` to remove it. How to find it back? 
I don't want to `docker pull` from the remote registry again, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rest DELETE action is called by [`api/client/rmi.go#L34`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/b5d914188efa55e6cf1fcd14334b2c1b61181eea/api/client/rmi.go#L34), which in turn calls [`daemon/image_delete.go#L226`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/7787d6dc2882def6bc125395c924827d30bd8a03/daemon/image_delete.go#L226)

```
daemon.Graph().Delete(img.ID)
```

That calls [graph/graph.go#L364-L375](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/ed9434c5bb64f49db442027e5e748bfbb46d0a0a/graph/graph.go#L364-L375) which does:

```
tmp, err := graph.mktemp()
os.Rename(graph.imageRoot(id), tmp)
// Remove the trashed image directory
return os.RemoveAll(tmp)
```

So it does appear to delete the files from the `imageRoot` folder (if there is no conflict, meaning if the image is not referenced by anything else).

In that case, the answer would be that you cannot find that image back without pulling it again.